# Remove type synonym in instance declaration of a contravariant functor

Tags: haskell

If I define:

```
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (b -> a) -> f a -> f b

type Op r a = (->) a r
```

And want to define:

```
instance Contravariant (Op r) where
    contramap f g = g . f
```

I get the error that instance type must not be synonyms. So I guess i need something akin to:

```
instance Contravariant ((->) _ r) where
    contramap f g = g . f
```

Which of course does not work. How can I get this instance of Contravariant to work ?

Comment: Try use newtype instead type to define Op. I'm not expert in hs, but type creates only an alias.

Comment: The constructor of a newtype must have exactly one field.

Comment: @vkubicki Your type has only one field, so that's no obstacle. It has two type parameters, but so what? Any `type` synonym can always be converted to a `newtype` instead, because they both have the same only-one-field restriction.

Comment: That is the error I get with `newtype Op r a = (->) a r`

Comment: ```newtype Op r a = Op (a -> r)```  is equivalent to ```newtype Op r a = Op ((->) a r)```

Comment: Haskell does not allow type-level lambdas nor partially applied type synonyms, which are nearly equivalent. Haskell only allows to define a `newtype` which is isomorphic to another type, allowing us to swap the argument order, as in `newtype Op r a = Op (a -> r)`. Note that according to this definition `Op r a` and `a -> b`  are _distinct_ types, albeit isomorphic ones. You will need to convert between these two types as needed (possibly using "safe coercions", or manual wrapping/unwrapping).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comments, the usual method is to define a `newtype`.  Note that the syntax is much the same as defining a `data` type, except that you use `newtype` in place of `data` and are only permitted one field.  In particular, you need a constructor, which is frequently given the same name as the type:

```
newtype Op r a =   Op      (a -> r)
--      ^^         ^^      ^^^^^^^^
--    newtype  constructor  field
```

This has the effect of defining a type isomorphic to `a -> r` but with the type parameter `a` coming "last" in the full type `Op r a`, which allows you to define a `Contravariant` instance for `Op r`.  Note that you'll need to unwrap and wrap the constructor where appropriate:

```
instance Contravariant (Op r) where
  contramap f (Op g) = Op (g . f)
```

For additional evidence that this is correct way to do it, note that the [definitions](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.27/base-4.13.0.0/src/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html) in `Data.Functor.Contravariant` from `base` are already set up like this, except they've decided to use a field accessor `getOp`:

```
-- from the Data.Functor.Contravariant source

newtype Op a b = Op { getOp :: b -> a }

instance Contravariant (Op a) where
  contramap f g = Op (getOp g . f)
```